# How to configure XCode and Client Options from Cordova's config.xml

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, continuous-integration

In compiling IOS applications, I have found no guide for the actual building of the XCode project files correctly, nor how to correctly control it from Cordova' config.xml code.

Currently, I need to do "things" on a build:

1. Fix the "#ifndef DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS" fence in AppDelegate.m.   I kludge this with this command line hack:

   ```
     sed -i "" -e "s/ifndef DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS/if 0/" build/cordova/platforms/ios/gThrive/Classes/AppDelegate.m
   ```
2. In XCode, I need to set the `Deployment Target` to 8.
3. In XCode, I need to set the `iPhone Device Oriention` checkboxes, because Corodova's orientation flag only sets the IPad.
4. In XCode, I need to click the `App Icons Source` button, which prompts to migrate to an asset catalog.
5. In XCode, I often have to set the Product/Destination be to a real device instead of an emulator.
6. I still Product/Clean, Product/Build, Archive:Verify[Validate & Submit to App Store, often selecting a provision developer id].

There must be a way to set these from the command line or from within Corodova's config.xml file.  I want the whole setup to just run.

Any ideas on any/all of these steps?

Comment: Did you ever come to find a solid guide for doing all of this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with shenzhen/ipa tool. Some Voodoo magic with xcode config file and you are done. You can use --xcconfig or --xcargs to overwrite default values.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get a command line dev build from Cordova 5.1.1 running on an iPhone without needing to go into XCode at all, or running xcodebuild or xcrun myself. As far as I can see the only difference between this and a release (distribution) build would be the need to set version and build numbers.

I don't know if the OP is still having problems, but if so I'll be glad to help.